# preg_replace REGEX

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I wanted some help regarding REGEX.

I have the following in a string variable after scraping from a website.

```
16:50 to 17:50 OOPS LAB : Scheduled Class : Shikha Jain : E1-0LA4&amp;nbsp;Download Course materials 15:45 to 16:45 OOPS LAB : Scheduled Class : Shikha Jain : E1-0LA4&amp;nbsp;Download Course materials 14:40 to 15:40 FR - III : Scheduled Class : Ravi Shankar Kumar : E3-218&amp;nbsp;Download Course materials &amp;nbsp;
```

What i want to do is, get rid of the "&nbsp;Download Course materials" part. I tried the str_replace and preg_replace but they all kept failing to replace successfully.
Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the ampersand has been replaced by an entity: `&amp;nbsp;` (thanks Viktor) :

```
$new_string = str_replace('&amp;nbsp;Download Course materials', '', $your_string)
```

Should do the job.

Comment: Exactly, but also note that the ampersand has been replaced by an entity: `&amp;nbsp;`.

Comment: Yeah that's often caused by htmlentities double encoding &  - for instance I often see &amp;amp; :\ A "double encode" boolean was added as another parameter in htmlentities() with PHP 5.2.3 - http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: thanks! btw, the string im using is an htmlentitied (if i can use that term) string.